# Misplaced SVG Path in raphael-svg-import

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm trying to render these files http://registro.soveci.com/dom_izq.svg and http://registro.soveci.com/dom_der.svg with RaphaelJS and raphael-svg-import, but somehow a path appears misplaced on the screen. If you view it with a standard compliant browser, you can see the path being rendered right, so it must be a problem with raphael-svg-import.

Can you provide me some hints??? (I'm new to SVG)

Answer (score 1):

I have been experimenting with SVG for a little bit now and it's a bit of a coincidence because I just finished playing with that plugin today.

The url to a [demo](http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/getSVG.php) I have there also contains zip files in the documentation so you could experiment with these in Inkscape or any SVG editor and see if you cannot configure them to something in your project.

For what ever reason this plugin "likes" some SVG's but not others so maybe you could adapt one of the SVGs in the zip and it will probably work.

The authors know the plugin does not always work but it is gradually improving and even now I think it's possible to write compatible SVG's if you tinker with them.

If you need a facility to convert certain SVG's just to javascript you could use [this](http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/SVGTOHTML_LIVE.php).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just need to know a couple more of things: 1) Once I've converted the SVG to Raphael, how can I manipulate the DOM? For instance, how do I retrieve a path? 2) How can I perform zooming? I know I can set a ViewBox, but what I don't understand so far, is what the dimensions of that ViewBox means, should I define my paths in terms of ViewBox coordinates so the browser then performs a transformation to user space coordinates?

Comment: YOU ASKED:1) Once I've converted the SVG to Raphael, how can I manipulate the DOM? For instance, how do I retrieve a path?

Comment: YOU ASKED:1) Once I've converted the SVG to Raphael, how can I manipulate the DOM? For instance, how do I retrieve a path? You can always get a path or any other object from in memory storage. In your code it will be arrayName[index]=paper.path... Then you can always subsequently do other stuff to thr object. You can store objects to disc. YOU ASKED 2) How can I perform zooming? ANSWER Another coincidence I recorded an effort by someone in the Raphael community today: www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?v=2&q=zooming